# SQL: How to use CASE WHEN output in new column calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to use the output of a CASE WHEN for a different column calculation, but I do not quite know how to.

Example:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (T.Delivery_Option = 'International Standard') AND (T.[Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge]) < 50 THEN 4.99 
    WHEN (T.Delivery_Option = 'International Standard') AND (T.[Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge]) >= 50 THEN 0
    ELSE 0
END AS 'Test',
```

What would I need to do, to use the output of "Test" in a different calculation such as:

```
T.[Net_Qty] / test
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to reuse it would probably be to use a [common table expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE 
               WHEN (T.Delivery_Option = 'International Standard') AND (T.[Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge]) < 50 THEN 4.99 
               WHEN (T.Delivery_Option = 'International Standard') AND (T.[Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge]) >= 50 THEN 0
               ELSE 0
           END AS Test
    FROM T
)
SELECT Net_Qty / Test
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to put your current logic into a CTE and then subquery it:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN Delivery_Option = 'International Standard' AND [Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge] < 50 THEN 4.99 
             WHEN Delivery_Option = 'International Standard' AND [Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge] >= 50 THEN 0
             ELSE 0 END AS test
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT [Net_Qty] / test AS item
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give i a go - but it might be beyond my SQL knowledge for now

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery like this

```
SELECT R.Test*5 FROM (

SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (T.Delivery_Option = 'International Standard') AND (T.[Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge]) < 50 THEN 4.99 
    WHEN (T.Delivery_Option = 'International Standard') AND (T.[Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge]) >= 50 THEN 0
    ELSE 0
END AS 'Test'
FROM TBL T

) as R
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server supports lateral joins.  This is a nifty feature that allows you to define new columns in the `FROM` clause . . . and they can then be used throughout the query:

```
SELECT . . .,
       v.test,
       t.Net_Qty / NULLIF(v.Test, 0)
FROM T CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN T.Delivery_Option = 'International Standard' AND T.[Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge] < 50 THEN 4.99 
                  WHEN T.Delivery_Option = 'International Standard' AND T.[Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge] >= 50 THEN 0
                 ELSE 0
              END)
     ) v(Test)
```

Also note the use of `NULLIF()`.  `Test` can easily take on `0` values, so you need to take that into account.  In fact, the second `WHEN` is not needed because it returns the same value as the `ELSE`, so this can be simplified to:

```
FROM T CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN T.Delivery_Option = 'International Standard' AND T.[Net_Qty] * T.[Unit_Charge] < 50 THEN 4.99 
                 ELSE 0
              END)
     ) v(Test)
```